# Different programming language environment using \newtcblisting

Tags: python, lstdefinestyle, matlab-prettifier, tcbinputlisting

In the code given below, I am attempting to generate different programming languages syntax environments.  With the current code, I am not able to get output to show up with color highlighted syntax and background color. Also, the naming of the different programming code is not showing up correctly.  For the Matlab code, the caption should show "Matlab Code 1: Some Matlab Code".  For the Python code, the caption should show "Python Code 1: Some Python Code.  The numbers should increment depending on what code is being presented.

I would like some help to get the colors to show up correctly for the different programming language environment and also the numbering to increment for the different programming languages.

Any guidance and help is sincerely appreciated!  Thanks!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Python Code}
\lstdefinestyle{pycode}{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends, import},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\lstdefinestyle{mcode}{
    style = {Matlab-editor},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Gray!80}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    backgroundcolor=\color{myblueiii},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

%\lstnewenvironment{myPyCode}
%{\lstset{style=pycode}}
%{}
%
%\lstnewenvironment{myMatCode}
%{\lstset{style=mcode}}
%{}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{pycode}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm]([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{mcode}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-b}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}


\begin{document}

\begin{mcode}{Some Matlab Code}
V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);
P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);
W = diag([0.1, 1*pi/180].^2);
map = LandmarkMap(20);
veh = Bicycle('covar', V);
veh.add_driver( RandomPath(map.dim) );
\end{mcode}

\begin{pycode}{Some Python Code}
"""
===============

Many plot types can be combined in one figure to create
powerful and flexible representations of data.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# np.random.seed(19680801)
# data = np.random.randn(2, 100)
#
# fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5))
# axs[0, 0].hist(data[0])
# axs[1, 0].scatter(data[0], data[1])
# axs[0, 1].plot(data[0], data[1])
# axs[1, 1].hist2d(data[0], data[1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.fill_between(x, y, color='#539ecd')
\end{pycode}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider using Pygments (and pygmentex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- Syntax highlight is supported by BOTH the `language=...` key AND your style of the `listings` library/package, like `keywordstyle`, `commentstyle`, `stringstyle`, and `numberstyle` (for line numbers). Pass color commands to these styles in your `\lstdefinestyle` (or inside the `listing options` key of `\newtcblisting`), and you will get highlight.

  ***Edited comment**: I am not familar with the matlab syntax style `Matlab-editor` you are using. If it doesn't work well, try the primary `language=Matlab` arg supported by the tcolorbox package.*
- Background color is controlled by the `colback` key. As you defined, it is `light-gray`.
- The title can be defined by the tcblisting's `title` key. For the auto numbering, I manually create counters for both Python and Matlab, and pass `use counter=<counter name>` option to the `\newtcblisting` command.

Here is the MWE that only includes core commands to address above-mentioned issues:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{pycode}{
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    language=Python
}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstdefinestyle{mcode}{
    style={Matlab-editor}
}

\newcounter{pylst}
\newtcblisting[use counter=pylst]{pycode}[2][]{%
    colback=white,
    title={#2}, coltitle=black,
    detach title,
    after upper={\par\centering Python Code~\thetcbcounter:~\tcbtitle},
    listing only,
    listing options={style=pycode},
    #1
}

\newcounter{mlst}
\newtcblisting[use counter=mlst]{mcode}[2][]{%
    colback=white,
    title={#2}, coltitle=black,
    detach title,
    after upper={\par\centering Matlab Code~\thetcbcounter:~\tcbtitle},
    listing only,
    listing options={style=mcode},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

A python code environment:

\begin{pycode}{Py title}
import numpy as np  # Import
\end{pycode}

A Matlab example:
\begin{mcode}{Matlab title}
X = eye(4);
\end{mcode}

Another python example:
\begin{pycode}{Py title2}
s = "Helloworld"
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

The output would be like:

[image: Sample output picture]