# Add option to point to code file in \tcblisting environment

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, tcbinputlisting

This question is building off the code and solution found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530446/different-programming-language-environment-using-newtcblisting).  I would like to add the option to point the actual code file (either a Matlab or Python code file) and put that into my options.  I have the current command

`\begin{mcode}{Some Matlab Code}{matcode1.m}` that specifies that this is a Matlab environment `mcode`, the name of the script (in this case "Some Matlab Code") and finally the path to the file.

For some reason, the `filecontents` contents do not show up in their respective environments and I just output these "empty" cells:

[image]

Can you tell me what I need to do, to have the contents of the file show up in their respective environments?  Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{matcode1.m}
V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);
P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);
W = diag([0.1, 1*pi/180].^2);
map = LandmarkMap(20);
veh = Bicycle('covar', V);
veh.add_driver( RandomPath(map.dim) );
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{pycode1.py}
"""
===============
Many plot types can be combined in one figure to create
powerful and flexible representations of data.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# np.random.seed(19680801)
# data = np.random.randn(2, 100)
#
# fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5))
# axs[0, 0].hist(data[0])
# axs[1, 0].scatter(data[0], data[1])
# axs[0, 1].plot(data[0], data[1])
# axs[1, 1].hist2d(data[0], data[1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.fill_between(x, y, color='#539ecd')
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Python Code}
\lstdefinestyle{pycode}{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends, import},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\lstdefinestyle{mcode}{
    style = {Matlab-editor},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Gray!80}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    %backgroundcolor=\color{cyan!20},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

%\lstnewenvironment{myPyCode}
%{\lstset{style=pycode}}
%{}
%
%\lstnewenvironment{myMatCode}
%{\lstset{style=mcode}}
%{}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}

\newcounter{pylst}
\newtcblisting[use counter=pylst]{pycode}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={style=pycode, xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut Python Code~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm]([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
        listing file = {#3}, #1}

\newcounter{mlst}
\newtcblisting[use counter=mlst]{mcode}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=cyan!20,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-b}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={style=mcode, xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut Matlab Code~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
        listing file = {#3}, #1}


\begin{document}

\begin{mcode}{Some Matlab Code}{matcode1.m}
\end{mcode}

\begin{pycode}{Some Python Code}{pycode1.py}
\end{pycode}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to use `\newtcbinputlisting` instead of `\newtcblisting`. The latter expects the listing contents to be provided as the body of the environment you are defining (in your case: empty). On the other hand, `\newtcbinputlisting` uses the file named by `/tcb/listing file` as input.

Before running the following code, make sure `matcode1.m` and `pycode1.py` don't already exist in the directory in which LaTeX is run, because previous runs of `\newtcblisting` would have truncated them to size zero, and `filecontents` or `filecontents*` without the `overwrite` option wouldn't rewrite them. Alternatively, you can use `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{〈file name〉} ... \end{filecontents}` if your LaTeX kernel is from October 2019 or later (which supersedes the `filecontents` package, see the [LaTeX News Issue number 30](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews30.pdf)).

(just prepend `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` at the very top of the file in case your LaTeX kernel is too old)

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{matcode1.m}
V = diag([0.02, 0.5*pi/180].^2);
P0 = diag([0.005, 0.005, 0.001].^2);
W = diag([0.1, 1*pi/180].^2);
map = LandmarkMap(20);
veh = Bicycle('covar', V);
veh.add_driver( RandomPath(map.dim) );
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{pycode1.py}
"""
===============
Many plot types can be combined in one figure to create
powerful and flexible representations of data.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# np.random.seed(19680801)
# data = np.random.randn(2, 100)
#
# fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5))
# axs[0, 0].hist(data[0])
# axs[1, 0].scatter(data[0], data[1])
# axs[0, 1].plot(data[0], data[1])
# axs[1, 1].hist2d(data[0], data[1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.fill_between(x, y, color='#539ecd')
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Python Code}
\lstdefinestyle{pycode}{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends, import},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\lstdefinestyle{mcode}{
    style = {Matlab-editor},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Gray!80}\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,
    framesep=2mm,
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
}

\newcounter{pylst}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=pylst]{\pycode}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={style=pycode, xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut Python Code~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm]([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
        listing file = {#3}, #1}

\newcounter{mlst}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=mlst]{\mcode}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=cyan!20,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-b}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={style=mcode, xleftmargin=-1mm},after upper={\centering\strut Matlab Code~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
        listing file = {#3}, #1}

\begin{document}

\mcode{Some Matlab Code}{matcode1.m}

\pycode{Some Python Code}{pycode1.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]